# Guessing Game Weighted Best Guess

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I encountered the following question in an interview for an internship and am still left wondering what the best solution to it is.

**Question:**

Suppose you are playing the guessing game. You can guess a number between 1 and n and you have an api to tell you if you are higher or lower.

Now suppose that each guess is weighted (i.e. you guess 20 so the cost is 20)

Create an algorithm to find the best first guess that minimizes the cost.

**What I was thinking:**

In the normal version of the problem (without weights) the solution is trivially binary search.

In this case however, I think I would need to perform average case analysis over all possible guess sequences which blows up the complexity of a solution. For example, I start off with a guess of 20 so I include the cost if the number was 20 and then find the next best guess (given that I can no longer guess 20) by performing a similar operation on a smaller space. I perform this for all first guesses and then take the minimum.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a dynamic programming problem, and you will end up working out the cost of the best cost for all intervals [i, j] with 1 <= i <= j <= 20.

For i=j the cost of guessing {i} is i.

To find the best cost of guessing for an interval [i, j] you consider all possible guesses k for i <= k <= j. The total cost using guess k is k + p * best cost for [i, k-1] + q * best cost for [k+1, j]. (score 0 cost for [i, j] when i > j). Assuming you are going for average cost then p will be (k - i) / (j + 1 - i) and q will be (j - k) / (j + 1 - i) and these should be the probabilities that the target is in [i, k - 1] and [k + 1, j].

You start with the best cost for all intervals of size 1. From these you can compute the best cost for all intervals of size 2, and you keep on from there to work out the best cost for all intervals of size 20. Then you normally backtrack to find out what all the best decisions are at each stage, probably using info you have stored as you have computed the costs. But in your case you only need to know the best first guess, so you can just store that as you compute it.

For N=20 you have O(N^2) best costs to work out, with each cost taking no more than O(N) work so we have an O(N^3) algorithm. Not great, but nothing like exponential, and for N=20 entirely affordable.

Comment: Average might not be a good idea. You should always assume that whenever you come up with a strategy, it will be against an adversary that goes for the weakest part. Considering that, you have to minimise the max.

Comment: @Raziman I agree that assuming a worst case adversary is usually sensible. I chose average/expected here because the original question mentioned it. I hope we agree that we can calculate the minimal worst case cost in much the same way, just using cost of current guess +  max(cost of best solution for each of the two intervals on either side of the point).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:  I wrote until the last part but then realised that I can't prove it, so I made this a community wiki so that someone with the right knowledge can fix it.**

Here's my solution; bear with me, there will be some math.  I will assume you want to minimize the expected cost, which is the average of the costs that your algorithm will spend for each of the possible values of the answer n (0 < n ≤ N).

First, what is your hunch on the answer?  Is it greater or smaller than N/2?

*(You: "Smaller")*

You say smaller?  That seems plausible, because choosing a bigger number to start with has greater cost.  But if you guess smaller, you are more likely to be told that the answer is higher than what you have guessed.  Then you'll incur more cost because the higher region costs more to make guesses in.

In the unweighted problem, if you choose something smaller than N/2 to start with, you'll be more likely to be told that the answer is higher, and you'll incur more cost too.  No good.

*(You: "Then it should be larger?")*

Well it has to be, if it isn't smaller.  (Unless I asked a trick question and the answer is actually N/2.  But I didn't.)  But how large?  Consider the unweighted problem again.  We chose the number in the middle, i.e. N/2.  Can we choose something middle-ish here?  The most obvious one is the number K, such that 1+2+3+4+...+K = (K+1)+(K+2)+(K+3)+(K+4)+...+N.  *(This is K = N/sqrt(2).)*  It turns out that this is the right answer.

*(You: "Why?  How can you expect me to believe you just like that?")*

Here's why:

Let's consider the unweighted problem first.  Why do we choose the N/2 first?  Surely you didn't just believe my waffly argument above?  What if we choose a K < N/2  instead?

*(You: "K is less than (N – K), so it won't be optimal.")*

Well, why won't it be optimal that way?  That isn't much of an argument if I didn't know that binary search works in the first place.  (Or if I didn't agree with the people who taught me that binary search works.)  Consider the following:

Let A(x) be the average cost required to guess a number from a range containing x elements, and let S(x) be the total cost, i.e. S(x) = xA(x).

Lets say we chose the middle element, N/2.  The total cost S(N) = S(N/2) + S(N – N/2) + N = 2S(N/2) + N.  *(The term N is the total cost for choosing the middle element – a cost of 1 per possible value of the answer n)*

What if we chose something less, K < N/2?  The total cost S(N) = S(K) + S(N – K) + N.

To show that choosing the middle element is not worse than choosing something less, we need to show that 2S(N/2) + N ≤ S(K) + S(N – K) + N, i.e. 2S(N/2) ≤ S(K) + S(N – K).

Consider the function A(x).  It is an increasing function, because when there is a larger range to choose from, it is not possible to be able to spend less.  (I could argue that if I could spend less for the larger range than the current one, I would simply extend the current one to the size of the larger range.)  *(Note: I do not claim that the function is *strictly* increasing, because it is unnecessary in my proof.)*

This means that S(x), which is the multiplication of the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) with an increasing function, is a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).  *(The proof of this statement is left as an exercise to the reader.)*

Hence, 2S(N/2) ≤ S(K) + S(N – K) is a consequence of the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality).  *(The special case of the Jensen's inequality required is the following: for any convex function f, 2f(x) ≤ f(x + k) + f(x – k).)*

If you choose a K > N/2, the argument is similar.

Let's now move on to your question proper.  What happens if it is weighted?  We can follow a similar strategy.

We will redefine S and A to take two parameters, the start and the end of the range (respectively), as it is two distinct ranges of the same size might have a different average cost and total cost.

If we choose the element which I claim is best, N/sqrt(2), the total cost is S(1, N) = S(1, N/sqrt(2)) + S(N/sqrt(2) + 1, N) + N * N/sqrt(2).

What about choosing a K < N/sqrt(2)?  The total cost is S(1, N) = S(1, K) + S(K + 1, N) + N * K.

We will need to show that S(1, N/sqrt(2)) + S(N/sqrt(2) + 1, N) + N * N/sqrt(2) ≤ S(1, K) + S(K + 1, N) + N * K.

A(x,y) is a convex function, since B(x,y) = A(x,y)/avg(x,y) is an increasing function where avg is some kind of averaging function.

The proof to this will probably need 2D convex functions where f(x, y+p) - f(x, y) <= f(x+q, y+p) - f(x+q, y).